# How do I calculate a projection to determine cost savings?

Tags: statistics

I have a problem. I have `8459` data points. These data points result in a savings of about `745.45` euros. Per year I have approx. `145148987` data points.

How do I now calculate an extrapolation for the whole year for these `8459` data points?

---

I could calculate something like this:

$$ \frac{745.45}{8459} = ~0.08812507 $$
$$ 0.08812507 * 145148987 = 12791265.20 $$

I would save about `12791265.20` for all data points - according to my calculation.

---

However, as far as I know it should be a free extrapolation - therefore the result would be wrong. Now how do I correctly calculate the savings for all data points?

Comment: You have a badly mixed up set of commas and periods.  This is the best you can do.  It assumes that the $8459$ points are representative of the rest.  If they are not, it may be very wrong, but without some sort of a model you can't do anything else.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the tip. I have adjusted it. 
So I have developed a model which gave me the saving for the `8459`. However, I would include a forecast/extrapolation of approximately how much could be saved for all `145148987` data points.

Comment: @RossMillikan Or do you mean by models, models that calculate the forecast/extrapolation for me? If so, what are they called?

Comment: You might have a reason to suspect that the savings per point will be less in the rest of the points than it has been so far.  Maybe the ones with the most savings were done first.  In that case the extrapolation should not be linear, but it depends on information that you feed in to make it better.  Nobody can help you without more information about what is going on